# when I try to open .JSP file in eclipse getting below error: How to fix this problem?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse I want to open the .jsp file but it gives the following error.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Search Marketplace for compatible editors (*.js)".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract even more details of that error from you log, it could make for an interesting bug report. In the meanwhile, you can install a compatible editor from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-enterprise-java-developer-tools .

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting same error i try to search for this error on internet.

As you can see in **Windows -Preference - Editors- File Association-** their will not able to found JSP editor. I don't what it could be a BUG or anything else.

I try to resolve by changing my eclipse version to **2020-06 to 2020-03**.

> **Now current i am using to 2020-03 it have JSP editor.**